# Updating React Component with multiple Redux actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I've been bashing my brain against this problem for awhile. Its a react app with redux state management. The problem is the component will not update when a click event is used to call a action. I'm rendering the button dynamically based on a certain prop in the state, if the button is clicked, it triggers a function that calls a prop which dispatches the action. Below is the code.

Here is the component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import {Table} from 'antd';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as rxActions from '../actions/rxActions';

const columns = [
    {
        title: 'Prescriber', dataIndex: 'doctor', rowKey: 'doctor'
    },
    {
        title: 'Submitted', dataIndex: 'timestamp', rowKey: 'timestamp'
    },
    {
        title: 'Prescription', dataIndex: 'prescription', rowKey: 'prescription'
    },
    {
        title: 'Refills', dataIndex: 'refills', rowKey: 'refills'
    },
    {
        title: 'Qty', dataIndex: 'quantity', rowKey: 'quantity'
    },
    {
        title: 'Exp', dataIndex: 'expDate', rowKey: 'exp'
    },
    {
        title: 'Status', dataIndex: 'status', rowKey: 'status'
    }
];

class RxHistory extends Component {

    handleFill(data) {
        this.props.fetchFillRx(
            {
                "patientID": this.props.onePatient.data.patientID,
                "rxid": data.rxid,
                "timestamp": moment(data.timestamp).valueOf(),
                "pharmacist": "pha",
                "phLicense": "pha01",
                "prescription": data.prescription,
                "refills": data.refills,
                "status": 'filled',
                "expDate": moment(data.expDate).valueOf()
            }
        )
    };

    handleApprove(data) {
        this.props.fetchApproveRx(
            {
                "patientID": this.props.onePatient.data.patientID,
                "rxid": data.rxid,
                "timestamp": moment(data.timestamp).valueOf(),
                "approved": "true"
            }
        )

    };

    checkStatus(data) {
        if (this.props.provider.type === 'pharmacist') {
            if (data.status !== 'filled') {
                return (
                    data.status = <button
                        type='button'
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.handleFill(data)
                        }}>
                        Fill Rx
                    </button>
                )
            }
            return (data.status = 'filled')
        }
        if (this.props.provider.type === 'insurance') {
            if (data.status === 'filled') {
                if (data.approved === 'false') {
                    return (
                        data.status = <button
                            type='button'
                            onClick={() => {this.handleApprove(data)}}>
                            Approve Rx
                        </button>
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        return data.status
    };

    renderTable() {
        if (this.props.rxHistory.isFetching) {
            return (
                <div className='ant-table-placeholder'>Loading...</div>
            )
        }
        if (this.props.rxHistory.rx.rxList) {
            const rxHistory = this.props.rxHistory.rx.rxList
                .map(data => {
                    data.timestamp = moment(data.timestamp).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                    data.expDate = moment(data.expDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                    data.status = this.checkStatus(data);
                    return data
                });
            if (this.props.provider.type !== 'doctor') {
                const reducedHistory = rxHistory.reduce((acc, data) => {
                    if (data.status !== 'filled' && data.approved !== 'true') {
                        acc.push(data);
                    }
                    return acc;
                }, []);

                return (
                    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={reducedHistory} rowKey={reducedHistory => reducedHistory.rxid}/>
                );
            }

            return (
                <Table columns={columns} dataSource={rxHistory} rowKey={rxHistory => rxHistory.rxid}/>
            );
        }

        return(
            <Table columns={columns} rowKey={null} />
        )
    }


    render() {
        return (
            this.renderTable()
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = ({ onePatient, rxHistory }) => {
    return { onePatient, rxHistory }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, rxActions)(RxHistory);
```

Here is the Action:

```
export const fetchFillRx = data => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: FILLING_RX});
    try {
        const res = await axios.patch(rxUrl, data);
        dispatch({
            type: FILL_RX,
            payload: res.data
        }).then(
            dispatch({type: FETCH_RX_HISTORY})
        )
    }
    catch (e) {
        dispatch({
            type: FILL_RX_ERROR,
            payload: e
        })
    }
};
```

Here is the reducer:

```
import {
    FILLING_RX,
    FILL_RX,
    FILL_RX_ERROR
} from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isFetching: false,
    res: ""
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FILLING_RX:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
            };

        case FILL_RX:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                res: action.payload,
            };

        case FILL_RX_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                res: "Failed to fill Rx",
            };

        default:
            return {
                ...state
            };
    }
};
```

The effects I've been experiencing is either an infinite loop when trying to use componentDidUpdate, or it will process the action, display the action in redux dev tools, but not update the component, or will say that the property of rxHistory.rx.rxList is undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I figured out that it has to do with a limitation of shallow comparisons made by redux. To solve the problem, I'd have to either write a very convoluted method of reducing each reducer to flatten the object, or alter that data structure to not have as many nested objects. The other solution would be to use a helper package that helps standardize the data.